# Определение региона по номеру телефона

Tags: php, веб-программирование

На сайте пользователь вводит номер телефона, а как можно по этому номеру узнать регион пользователя? Кто с таким сталкивался, товарищи???

Comment: Нельзя плодить дубликаты!

Comment: Вам уже дали ответ на этот вопрос, в предыдуший раз. Прекратите плодить дубликаты!